# Magento 2 Maintenance Mode IP filtering not working

Tags: magento2, command-line, maintenance

I hope you can help me with this issue.

I already enabled the `maintenance mode` and set up the `IP` filter, but it's not working. Although I configured to access the site with my `IP` I'm unable to see `front-end` and `back-end`, I only get the `503 Error` page.

I used all the common commands for the `manintenance mode` and even tried to configure a [redirection through .htaccess](https://inchoo.net/ecommerce/how-to-put-magento-in-maintenance-mode-with-ip-filters-the-easy-way/) with `IP` filter and doesn't work either.

Thank You.!

Comment: you have redis cache setup?

Comment: I have redis cache enabled. Is there any configuration which must be done regarding it?

Answer (score 1):

**First step:**

Run `php bin/magento maintenance:allow-ips 127.0.0.1` 
*where 127.0.0.1 your IP*

**Second step:**

Check on *your_site_path/var* folder .maintenance.ip file. Thes file should contain allowed IPs by comma-separated. If you didn't see it create this file manually 
 and run: `php bin/magento maintenance:enable`
also, Magento should be switched to production mode

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Already tried this and it's not working although the IP is being saved in the .maintenance.ip file. What can I do to make it work. Is there any other command I can use or any other configuration I should check?

Comment: Did you switched Magento to production mode?
You can also use a custom FREE  extension like this one 
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-better-maintenance/?utm_source=mageplaza&utm_medium=mageplaza&utm_campaign=mageplaza-review&utm_content=Better%20Maintenance

Comment: @msrz85 did you manage to exempt your IP? I'm struggling with the same situation.